# Object Destructuring ignoring values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to destructure and ignore few values, how do I do that?

For example:

```
const test = { name: 'John', age: 29, gender: 'male'}
function getData(...args) {
  const {,,gender} = args[0];
  console.log(gender); // should print male.
}

getData(test);
```

I want to ignore (not declare variables for) name and age parameters (so that my ESLint does not throw an error) at the same time use ES6.

The syntax `,` does not seem to work either. Any other workarounds for this problem?

Comment: objects have no sparse items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a single arg (the object), and you should object destructuring to get `gender`:

```js
const test = { name: 'John', age: 29, gender: 'male'}
function getData(arg) {
  const { gender} = arg;
  console.log(gender); // should print male.
}

getData(test);
```